# How to fake Manifest.xml for WSP builder solution

Tags: 2007, development, sandbox-solution, wspbuilder

I know WSP builder creates manifest at run time and then deletes it but can I fake it somehow to add few safe controls (I know other ways but I want to know if I can do it this way or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSPBuilder will only allows Safe Controls entries for objects that inherits from the "Control" class. A simple fix could be to create an empty class that inherits from `WebControl` and use the same namespace in your fake ascx file.